# Compare 2 values out of a string with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, compare

I have the following code which gets the current state of a set of licenses:

```
set licensefile="D:\PLM\Solid Edge ST10\Preferences\SElicense.dat"
set _output=lmutil lmstat -c %licensefile% -f "solidedgeclassic"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=()=" %%G IN ('%_output% ^|find "issued"') DO set line=%%G
```

This, sets %line% equal to the following string:

```
Total of 6 licenses issued;  Total of 5 licenses in use
```

Of course, these values can be changed, but the sentence will always be the same.
I would like the batch script to return an error if `5 >= 6`.

**How can I do this?**

**EDIT:** The result of the _output statement is:

```
lmutil - Copyright (c) 1989-2017 Flexera Software LLC. All Rights Reserved.
Flexible License Manager status on Thu 11/22/2018 09:05
[Detecting lmgrd processes...]
License server status: 27001@VIRT04
License file(s) on VIRT04: C:\SEFlex\Program\SELicense.dat:

VIRT04: license server UP v11.14.0

Vendor daemon status (on virt04):

 selmd: UP v11.14.0
Feature usage info:

Users of solidedgeclassic:  (Total of 6 licenses issued;  Total of 3 licenses in use)

  "solidedgeclassic" v110.0, vendor: selmd, expiry: permanent(no expiration date)
  floating license

    person1 PC-CAS016 PC-CAS016 (v110.0) (virt04/27001 1218), start Thu 11/22 8:00
    person2 PC-CAS09 PC-CAS09 (v110.0) (virt04/27001 599), start Thu 11/22 8:06
    person4 PC-CAS015 PC-CAS015 (v110.0) (virt04/27001 645), start Thu 11/22 8:51


Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `if value1 geq value2 ... `

Comment: Add space to the `tokens=`. `%%I` and `%%N` have the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am getting an idea of exactly what your data looks like, this might do:

```
@echo off
set licensefile="D:\PLM\Solid Edge ST10\Preferences\SElicense.dat"
set _output=lmutil lmstat -c %licensefile% -f "solidedgeclassic"

for /f "tokens=6,11" %%i in ('%_output% ^|find "issued"') do (
    if %%j geq %%i (
       echo Error %%j larger or equal %%i
     ) else (
       echo Success %%j less than %%i
   )
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the following code to extract the line of interest and therefrom the two numbers and store them into the variables `issued` and `used`, respectively, so the exact position of the expression in between parentheses or, expressed in another way, the number of preceding words, does not matter:

```cmd
for /f "tokens=2 delims=()=" %%G IN ('
    %_output% ^| findstr /R /C:"(Total of [0-9][0-9]* licenses issued;  *Total of [0-9][0-9]* licenses in use)"
') do (
    for /F "tokens=3,8" %%I in ("%%G") do (
        set "issued=%%I" & set "used=%%J"
    )
)
```

To output an error message and terminate the batch script with an [`ErrorLevel`](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) value of `1`, for example, do this then:

```cmd
if %used% geq %issued% (
    >&2 echo ERROR!
    exit /B 1
)
```